# Issue returning row content data alongside Max(score) by class & round, using group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to return the personal best for a user, by class & round; but the Date Shot is coming out incorrect. Help please - so frustrating!

```
SELECT 
    c.Class, 
    r.Round, 
    h.shootdate as 'Date Shot', 
    max(h.Score) AS 'Personal Best'
FROM history h, classes c, rounds r
WHERE c.id = h.classid AND r.id = h.roundid AND h.userid = 1
GROUP BY c.Class, r.Round
```

Comment: Instead of listing the tables and using the where to make a join, use the more standard JOIN syntax, Edit your question and show the schema of the tables, the results you are getting and an example of what you expect to get.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`!!!  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: "Date Shot is coming out incorrect" won't help us help you.  Incorrect how???  Blank???  Error out???  Wrong value???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self join on `history` table to pick a row with maximum score for each user per classid and roundid

```
SELECT 
    c.Class, 
    r.Round, 
    h.shootdate as 'Date Shot', 
    h.Score AS 'Personal Best'
FROM history h
JOIN (
    SELECT classid, roundid, max(score) score
    FROM history
    WHERE userid = 1
    GROUP BY classid, roundid
) h1 ON h.classid = h1.classid AND h.roundid = h1.roundid AND h.score = h1.score
JOIN classes c ON c.id = h.classid
JOIN rounds r ON r.id = h.roundid
-- WHERE h.userid = 1 // not necessary
```

In your query you are picking `shootdate` which is not present in group by that is why you are not getting correct value where score is max, Also use explicit join syntax to relate your tables

Comment: Many Thanks, 2nd where clause on userid IS needed